# R FUNCTION : .Rstudio

Tags: r

Any help in fixing my query would be appreciated. Also, for the purposes of this equation, I need to keep the basic format of the formula I've used:

Answer (score 1):

Here it is.
In the question the time `t` is hardcoded as `seq(1, 4, 1)`, hence the error. The function below uses `seq_len`.

```
c_rate <- function (bond_value, par, time, y) {
  time_seq <- seq_len(time)
  numer <- bond_value - par/(1 + y)^time
  denom <- par * sum((1 + y)^-time_seq)
  numer/denom
}

c_rate(1091.5946, 1000, 5, 0.03)
#[1] 0.0500001

c_rate(1000, 973.9658, 3, 0.06)
#[1] 0.06999999
```